# Header and content not aligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a div that fill using angular, this is the code.

```
<div ng-show="divSilt" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="portlet light form-fit bordered" style="padding: 12px 20px 0 20px;">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <div class="caption font-blue">
                            <i class="icon-speech brinksblue"></i>
                            <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase brinksblue"> Acompanhamento SILT</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body form">
                        <div style="overflow: auto;" class="alturaPagina">
                            <table md-table>
                                <thead fix-head md-head md-order="query.order">
                                <tr md-row>
                                    <th md-column style="box-sizing: content-box"><span>&nbsp;</span></th>
                                    <th md-column style="box-sizing: content-box" md-order-by="Dt_Execucao"><span>Data da Importação</span></th>
                                    <th md-column style="box-sizing: content-box" md-order-by="Cod_Regional"><span>Regional</span></th>
                                    <th md-column style="box-sizing: content-box" md-order-by="Cod_Filial" md-desc><span>Filial</span></th>
                                    <th md-column style="box-sizing: content-box" md-order-by="Dt_Inicio"><span>Início da Apuração</span></th>
                                    <th md-column style="box-sizing: content-box" md-order-by="Dt_Fim"><span>Fim da Apuração</span></th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody md-body>
                                <tr md-row ng-repeat="arquivo in vm.importacaoSilt | filter: filter.search | orderBy: query.order">
                                    <td md-cell><a href="" ng-click="vm.detalhes(arquivo)"><i class="fa fa-list" title="Detalhes" /></a></td>
                                    <td md-cell>{{arquivo.DT_DATA| date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                                    <td md-cell>{{arquivo.Cod_Regional}}</td>
                                    <td md-cell>{{arquivo.Cod_Filial}}</td>
                                    <td md-cell>{{arquivo.Dt_inicio | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                                    <td md-cell>{{arquivo.Dt_Termino | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I fill it comes with a problem in the align of the header and the content, see print below.

[image]

Now its the weird part time, when I press F12 to investigate the problem the alignment automatically is fixed, I open the console and its everything alright. If I refresh the page the problem happens again,someone know what is causing this?(Print below of right after I open Console)

[image]

Comment: Some live demo would help.

Comment: Another problem is,in the first screenshoot the first line of the grid is empty, when i open console the problem does't happen anymore.